# Excel - Populate cells based on dynamic condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have all the days in a year listed in column A (In American format, sorry!). Some of those days are "special" based on some other criteria somewhere else in the spreadsheet. I want to populate another column (D in the example below) only with the dates in column A meet a certain criteria (Column C is True). Desired (dynamic) output in Column D:

```
    A              B             C             D
1  Date        Day           SpecialDay     JustSpecials
2  1/1/2019    Tuesday       True           1/1/2019
3  1/2/2019    Wednesday     False          1/4/2019
4  1/3/2019    Thursday      False          1/5/2019
5  1/4/2019    Friday        True           1/6/2019
6  1/5/2019    Saturday      True           1/8/2019
7  1/6/2019    Sunday        True           1/9/2019
8  1/7/2019    Monday        False
9  1/8/2019    Tuesday       True
10 1/9/2019    Wednesday     True
```

So, if a day becomes special for some reason (False becomes True in Column C) then I want that date added to Column D automatically. I'm trying to shy away from using "higher level" Excel functionallity here as I will have to pass this system off to someone else some day, so preferably no VBA if possible.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try use `SMALL()` in an array formula like so:

Formula in `D2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,SMALL(($C$2:$C$10=TRUE)*ROW($C$2:$C$10),COUNTIF($C$2:$C$10,FALSE)+(ROW()-1))),"")
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Note that if your values are actually boolean just replace the textstrings in the comparison for the boolean values.

Another option for `D2` could be:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(0,IF($C$2:$C$10=TRUE,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$10),""),0)),"")
```

Also entered as array.

And another option, maybe even more userfriendly, is Pivot Table your range and filter Date on SpecialDay...

EDIT

After watching your video:

- Your first option shows `Date` cause you looked for textstrings instead of Boolean. Change the `True` and `False` textstrings to actually written boolean values `TRUE` and `FALSE`.
- Leave the `A1` reference, it is correct. The second part of the formula returns a true rownumber. Because you are using `INDEX()` it will start counting rows from the first row of that range. So `$A$1:$A$10` reference in my first formula is correct.
- Next thing your tried is using a `1` value for true values. This won't work. The formula will try to look for actually values being `1` which there are NON.  Therefor the formula will return an array of 0's. Resulting in no actual value, the index formula will return cell A1 then.

So probs for the video and the effort! The solution for you is to know how to write real boolean values `TRUE` and `FALSE`, they don't come with the double quotes. I'll update both formulas since you not using textstrings anyway.

Comment: I really appreciate your responses here. I've tried the first two and I cannot get them to work fully. The first one (using SMALL()) works on the first cell, but not on D3 and down. You are correct, I'm using boolean logic, so I change the "True" to a 1 and removed the quotes. Same with the "False" and 0.

Comment: Have you entered as array? Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: No, I wasn't. I just figured out what that means. However, now I get the word "Date" in the number of D cells equivilant to the number of TRUEs I have in Column C. When I change the formula to start at $A$2 instead of $A$1 I get only January 1st in six cells (that the number of "True" events).

Comment: I unfortunately can't test it for you comming days, but both options worked for me

Comment: @Michael : I think that I might see why you are getting only the "one" result.Select the entire D Column and press delete. Paste JvdV's  formula ONLY in cell D2.Then press Ctrl, Shift, Enter as he stated. Double- click the fill handle to fill down and then calculate the sheet. You should then see the same correct results that he is getting. I think that when you entered his formula, you entered it as a multi-celled Array, thus the 'one only' result.

Comment: Thanks @Roger H. I'm still not able. However, I made screenshot video and uploaded it to  youtube. [link](https://youtu.be/DQQ8mqeYITk)

Comment: Thanks for the link, untill ill be behind a pc tomorrow I won't be able to test myself, but for now change 1 to true and 0 to false. Who knows.

Comment: Try an alternative Array formula in Cell D1 and then fill down.Hopefully this will bypass the issue that you are having : =IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$100,SMALL(IF(B$1:B$100=TRUE,ROW(B$1:B$100),""),ROW())),""). Ctrl, Shift, Enter

Comment: I watched your video. After you filled down each version of the formula, did you not calculate the sheet (Shift F9)? You have to calculate in order to update the continuing and changing values for each Row value. If that's the case, then you don't even need to use my alternative formula. JvdV's formulas all work.

Comment: @RogerH. It's because OP used quotation marks, the wrong cell reference, plus a 1 and 0 instead of real boolean values wont work in this case. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks to both of you JvdV and @RogerH. I really appreciate it!